# Contradictory results of numerical evaluations of a function

Tags: numerical-integration, numerics, numerical-value

I have the following function:

```
f[a_,b_,A_,m1_,x_] := Sum[2^(3 + 4 m) (1/a + 1/b)^(-2 (1 + m))Gamma[2 + 2 m] Hypergeometric1F1[2 (1 + m), 1/2, -((a b x^2)/(A^2 (a + b)))], {m, 0, m1}];
```

This is the result of the following integral:

```
Sum[Integrate[y^(4 m + 3) Cos[x/A y] E^(-y^2/4 (1/a + 1/b)), {y, 0, \[Infinity]}, Assumptions -> Re[m] > -1 && Re[1/a + 1/b] > 0], {m,0,m1}]
```

The limit of the function when $x \rightarrow \infty$ should be 0, as the terms of the sum go to $0$ as $m \to \infty$:

```
In: Limit[((2 a)/(a + b) - 1)^(2 m)   ((2^(3 - 2 m)) Gamma[2 + 2 m] )/Gamma[1 + m]^2, m -> \[Infinity], Assumptions -> Vxx > 0 && Vyy > 0]
Out: 0
```

and, using the asymptotic representation of the confluent hypergeometric function $_1F_1(a,b,z)$: $$\Gamma(b)\left(\frac{e^x x^{a - b}}{\Gamma(a)} + \frac{-x^{-a}}{\Gamma(b - a)}\right)$$

We get:

```
In: Limit[Gamma[b] ((E^x x^(a - b))/Gamma[a] + (-x)^-a/Gamma[b - a]) /. a -> 2 (1 + m) /. b -> 1/2 /. x -> -((x^2 a b)/(a + b)), x -> \[Infinity], Assumptions -> m >= 0 && Vxx > 0 && Vyy > 0 && A > 0]
Out: 0
```

So, for large $x$, I would expect the function to decrease to $0$.

Now, I have two different problems that, I suspect, are related.

**1. When I evaluate the function at large values of $x$, I get contradictory results:**

```
       In[1]: q = f[2, 3, 2, 3, x] // N;
              q /. x -> 100
       Out[1]: -5.76 + 0. I

       In[2]: f[2, 3, 2, 3, 100] // N
       Out[2]: 3.03645*10^26 + 0. I


       In[3]: f[2., 3., 2., 3., 100.] // N
       Out[3]: 9.61733*10^-7

       In[4]: FullSimplify[f[2, 3, 2, 3, 100]] // N
       Out[4]: -3.02833*10^29
```

And I tried to use the integral form to check, but the same thing happened:

```
       In[1]: Integrate[y^(4 m + 3) Cos[x/A y] E^(-y^2/4 (1/a + 1/b)) /. a -> 2. /. b -> 3. /. A -> 2. /. m -> 3. /. x -> 100., {y, 0, \[Infinity]}, Assumptions -> Re[m] > -1 && Re[1/a + 1/b] > 0]
       Out[1]: 8.76703*10^-16

       In[2]: Integrate[y^(4 m + 3) Cos[x/A y] E^(-y^2/4 (1/a + 1/b)) /. a -> 2 /. b -> 3 /. A -> 2 /. m -> 3 /. x -> 100, {y, 0, \[Infinity]}, Assumptions -> Re[m] > -1 && Re[1/a + 1/b] > 0]
       Out[2]: (15479341056 (-1528415185117230896460916 + 30563207285404851812924775 Sqrt[30] DawsonF[10 Sqrt[30]]))/78125
       In[3]: (15479341056 (-1528415185117230896460916 + 30563207285404851812924775 Sqrt[30] DawsonF[10 Sqrt[30]]))/78125 // N
       Out[3]: -3.02833*10^29

       In[4]: NIntegrate[FullSimplify[y^(4 m + 3) Cos[x/A y] E^(-y^2/4 (1/a + 1/b))] /. a -> 2 /. b -> 3 /. A -> 2 /. m -> 3 /. x -> 100, {y, 0, \[Infinity]}]
       Out[4]: 104.409
```

For `In[3]`, I got the following error:[image]

And for `In[4]`: [image]

**2. When I plot the function(s), I get unexpected graphs:**

**First graph:** `f[2, 3, 2, x, 3] = s` (blue); `N[f[2, 3, 2, x, 3]] = N[s]` (red); `FullSimplify[N[f[2, 3, 2, x, 3]]] = FullSimplify[N[s]]` (black). There are some oscillations at larger $x$, and different graphs for `s`, `N[s]` and `FullSimplify[N[s]]`.
[image]

**Second graph:** `f[2, 3, 2, x, 3] = s` (blue); `N[f[2, 3, 2, x, 3]] = N[s]` (red). Very large oscillations at larger x, different graphs for `s`, `N[s]` and `FullSimplify[N[s]]`, and we can see that the function stabilizes at a constant value, that's different from $0$.
[image]

**Third graph:** `f[2, 3, 2, x, 3] = s` (blue); `N[f[2, 3, 2, x, 3]] = N[s]` (red). Close-up of `s` and `N[s]`, with different values.
[image]

**Fourth graph:** `f[2, 3, 2, x, 3] = s` (blue); `N[f[2, 3, 2, x, 3]] = N[s]` (red); `FullSimplify[N[f[2, 3, 2, x, 3]]] = FullSimplify[N[s]]` (black). Although `s` and `N[s]` stabilize at values different from $0$, `FullSimplify[N[s]]` seems to decrease (or grow) exponentially as $x$ gets larger, which contradicts the limit computed earlier.
[image]

As the function is an infinite sum in terms of $m$, as $m$ gets larger, the terms should be closer and closer together. But I plotted three variants of `f[2,3,2,110,m]` for values of $m$ going from $0$ to $20$, and this is the result:

**Fifth graph:** `f[2,3,2,110,m]//FullSimplify//N`; it grows exponentially as m gets larger.
[image]

**Sixth (and final) graph:** `f[2.,3.,2.,110.,m]` (blue); `f[2,3,2,110,m]` (red).
[image]

Here is the code for the graphs:

```
 (*1, 2, 3, 4*) Plot[Evaluate[{f[2, 3, 2, 3, t], f[2, 3, 2, 3, t]//N, f[2, 3, 2, 3, t]//N//FullSimplify}], {t, 0, 60}, ImageSize -> Large, PlotLegends -> {"s", "N[s]","FullSimplify[N[s]]"}, PlotStyle -> {{Red, Opacity[1]}, {Blue, Opacity[0.5]}, {Black, Opacity[1]}}]
 (*5*) ListLogLogPlot[Table[f[2, 3, 2, n, 110] // N // FullSimplify, {n, 0, 20}]]
 (*6*) Show[ListPlot[Table[f[2., 3., 2., n, 110.], {n, 0., 20.}]], ListPlot[Table[f[2, 3, 2, n, 110.], {n, 0, 20}], PlotStyle -> Red], PlotRange -> Automatic]
```

Is there an avoidable reason behind the strange behavior of Mathematica?

Comment: Machine precision is insufficient for such small numbers. Don't use just `N` to obtain the numerical value; instead use arbitrary-precision by specifying a desired precision with e.g. `N[..., 20]` or however many digits of precision you think you need.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With differences of numbers of the order of E^3000 you are in danger to overshoot machine precision.

You can see this e.g.:

```
f[a_, b_, A_, m1_, x_] := 
  Sum[2^(3 + 4 m) (1/a + 1/b)^(-2 (1 + m)) Gamma[
     2 + 2 m] Hypergeometric1F1[2 (1 + m), 
     1/2, -((a b x^2)/(A^2 (a + b)))], {m, 0, m1}];

q = f[2, 3, 2, 3, x];

f[2, 3, 2, 3, 100] == q /. x -> 100

(*True*)
```

Therefore, your calculation is correct up to where you use `N`. If subsequent calculations are needed, they must be done using arbitrary precision and not machine precision.